# Does a SELECT COUNT(*) query have to do a full table scan?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

Does a query that gets the count of all rows in a table have to do a full table scan or does SQL Server maintain a count of rows somewhere?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

The table `TABLE_NAME` has a primary key, and therefore a clustered index, and looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME
(
  Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: no, it will look up every row in the table, msql server will not maintain a counter

Comment: The server does maintain a row count *elsewhere*, in `sys.partitions`. The query you wrote won't use it though. The query optimizer could decide to use a table scan or scan an index

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The server will always read all records (if there's an index then it will scan the entire index) to count the rows. You can't escape this as long as you are doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table`.

If your table has a clustered index, you can [change your query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130604/4608204) to an "under the hood" query to retrieve the count without actually fetching the records with:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.id) [Table_Name], i.rowcnt [Row_Count]
FROM sys.sysindexes i WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE i.indid in (0,1)
ORDER BY i.rowcnt desc
```

if you are looking for an ***approximate*** count of the records, you can also use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.NAME,
    SchemaName = s.Name,
    [RowCount] = p.rows,
    TotalSpaceMB = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 / 1024.0), 
    UsedSpaceMB = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 / 1024.0),
    UnusedSpaceMB = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 / 1024.0)
FROM 
    sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, 
    s.Name, 
    p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC
```

This will show non-system tables with their calculated (not exact) row count and the sum of the sizes of their data (with any index they might have), relatively fast without retrieving the records.

Answer (score 6):

When SQL Server performs a query like `SELECT COUNT(*)`, SQL Server will use the narrowest `non-clustered index` to count the rows. If the table does not have any `non-clustered index`, it will have to scan the table.

If your table has a `clustered index` you can get your count even faster.

Comment: So, if the table has a primary key and therefore a clustered index, does SQL Server do a full table scan or not? How does it then get the row count?

Comment: If table have primary key then it will not do the full table scan. For your reference http://dbatipster.blogspot.com/2009/08/get-row-counts-fast.html

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 No - do not assume the primary key and the clustered index are always the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Does a full table scan.

For optimizations you can refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martijnh/2010/07/15/sql-serverhow-to-quickly-retrieve-accurate-row-count-for-table/).

Answer (score 0):

you can following way. it is better in performance I guess.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Myth - you will get the same exact query plan.

Comment: I could see the difference in query output time if I go for count(*) and count(1)