# Select query on primary key column of 500+ million rows table is not responding

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-performance, large-data

I have a table in SQL Server having 500+ million rows with default clustered index defined on the primary key of table. I am running this simple query which takes more than 30 minutes.

```
Select count(ledgeridXXX) from Ledger.dbo.tblXXXX
```

Here is the chunk of clustered index definition

```
CONSTRAINT [PK__tblDepar__AE70E0AFF9BAF7B9] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LedgerIDXXX] ASC
) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I don't have any clue where it could be wrong and why is it taking so much time. Please suggest me some ways or techniques on how to fix it as this is a critical table and main reporting heavily relies on this table.

Comment: Have you tried `count(*)`? Is that column nullable?

Comment: No, its a primary key of the table. I don't want * as this would increase more time.

Comment: Show us the estimated execution plan using Paste The Plan.

Comment: If it's not null then why would that increase anything?

Comment: It's a myth that has never been true that `count(not_null_column)` is faster than `count(*)` - the performance for both is absolutely identical. So `count(*)` won't change anything, I am quite certain that SQL Server uses the exact same execution plan for both. I guess there is not much you can do, except for throwing faster hardware on the problem or maybe make SQL Server use a parallel threads for the counting. But in the end it has to go all rows in the table to do the counting

Comment: @DaleK please see the plan

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJhkGzCQP

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Basically I wanted to be on a safer side so I was just checking on single column which has index to check the performance. Thank you for the update.

Comment: @shawnt00 I meant to say that I just need a single coulmn count response time to check the sql table performance

Comment: I was thinking that SQL Server did allow a primary key on a nullable column. Maybe that's because I was just reading up on SQLite quirks. I would try these approaches although I believe some only given approximate answers. And honestly I wasn't sure if this had changed in the last few versions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921610/does-a-select-count-query-have-to-do-a-full-table-scan

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/martijnh/sql-serverhow-to-quickly-retrieve-accurate-row-count-for-table

Comment: @shawnt00 I will surely read these articles. My main concern is with the table performance right now and I am clueless

Answer (score 1):

if you are just counting the number of rows, you can try this:

```sql
SELECT SUM(p.rows) as [cnt]
FROM sys.partitions AS p
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE p.index_id = 1 /* clustered index */
AND t.name = N'tblXXXX'AND s.name = N'dbo';
```

the `COUNT(clusteredkey)` will probably have some overhead when you have intensive workload. this can take hours scanning the entire 500million rows.

if you are running higher version of SQL Server, you can use the columnstore index to speed up the `COUNT`.

References:

1. [Bad habits - Count The Hard Way](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way)
2. [Fast count - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069237/fastest-way-to-count-exact-number-of-rows-in-a-very-large-table)
3. [Columnstore Index Fast Count](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6283/faster-sql-server-select-count-queries-with-columnstore-indexes/)

Comment: Tried this, with a table of 145M rows, went instant. Thanks for the great query !

Comment: This is just a dummy query, this table is used by sp with different requirements

Comment: i provided a couple of technique you can use. You did not mentioned any sp/other requirements on your original question. what do you mean by _"this table is used by sp with different requirementssp and what different requirements"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do `COUNT(Column)`, `COUNT(1)`, `COUNT(*)` without the `where` clause:

SQL Server finds the smallest (containing the least amount of columns, the most rows in a single AK page) index that will do the job.

If you only have a clustered index, this means it will use the clustered index. (The clustered index contains all columns of the table)

What you can do to speed things up:

1. Create a separate index with only 1 column, preferably a small data type. (The index creation can take lots of time).
2. Create an indexed view for your query. Since you aren't grouping I wouldn't recommend this.
3. Specify table hints `WITH(TABLOCK)` or `WITH(TABLOCKX)` to force a table lock or exclusive table lock.